# Hiding a div if property is equal to one in php

Tags: php

Once user click on view details i am displaying the property details of the particular property.If the property type value is Open Plots then i dont want to display the car parking div.I have written a code for that but getting error as unexpected '<'

Here is the code which i have written:

```
<?php session_start();
include 'db.php';   
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_properties WHERE property_id = $id";
$oppointArr =array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
  {          
    $oppointArr = $row;           
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}
?>

        <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='property_id'>
    <div class="property-specs">
                            <ul class="specs-list">
                                <li><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-double-king-size-bed"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['property_type'];?></li>
                                <li><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-copy"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['area_sqft'];?> Sqft</li>
                                <li><div class="icon"><span class="fa fa-compass"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['facing'];?> Facing</li>
                                <li id="car_parking"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-private-garage"></span></div>
                                <?php if((<?php echo $oppointArr['property_type'];?>)=='Open-Plots')
                                {
                                    <?php echo 'style="display:none;"';?>
                                }
                                else{
                                <?php echo $oppointArr['car_parking'];?>
                                }
                                </li>
                                <li id="total_bathrooms"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-vintage-bathtub"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['total_bathrooms'];?> Bathrooms</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Your php tags are messed up and you have a bunch of echo on the PHP in your li elements

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your code condition with following.**

```
<?php session_start();
include 'db.php';   
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_properties WHERE property_id = $id";
$oppointArr =array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
  {          
    $oppointArr = $row;           
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}
$display = 'block';
if(($oppointArr['property_type'])=='Open-Plots'){
    $display = 'none';
}
?>

<input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='property_id'>
<div class="property-specs">
    <ul class="specs-list">
        <li><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-double-king-size-bed"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['property_type'];?></li>
        <li><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-copy"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['area_sqft'];?> Sqft</li>
        <li><div class="icon"><span class="fa fa-compass"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['facing'];?> Facing</li>
        <li id="car_parking" style="display:<?php echo $display?>">><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-private-garage"><?php echo $oppointArr['car_parking'];?></span></div></li>
        <li id="total_bathrooms"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-vintage-bathtub"></span></div> <?php echo $oppointArr['total_bathrooms'];?> Bathrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is printing style="display:none; i dont wont to display the total field should be hided

Comment: This will hide your li tag if condition matched

Comment: It is displaying the icon total li should not be displayed

Comment: add screenshot here , also print the value of $display and check

Comment: your answer shouldn't be code-only. A good answer provides info as well to help the OP and future readers learn from it

Comment: It is printing style="display:none; i dont wont to display the total field should be hided  - total field means last li with id="total_bathrooms" ?

Comment: @treyBake will take care it next time thanks  for the suggestion

Comment: @Priyank  i have changed the span and id little bit its working fine  <li style="display:<?php echo $display?>"><div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-private-garage"></span></div><?php echo $oppointArr['car_parking'];?></li>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  if($oppointArr['property_type']=='Open-Plots'){
     echo 'style="display:none;"';
  }else{
     echo $oppointArr['car_parking'];
  }
?>
```

is this way better?

Comment: It is printing style="display:none; i dont wont to display the total field should be hided